# ffmpeg - thread_queue_size

Tags: ffmpeg

What is the exact reason of this warning in ffmpeg

```
Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
```

Im sending through the pipe yuv420 video to ffmpeg and streaming to youtube. When warning appears i get fps drops.
Increasing value will help for a while.

Comment: What did you raise it to?

Comment: 512, above im hitting ram limit(rasbperry pi 3)